# faster update query in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

can any body suggest which one would be faster for execution(Consider handling large data more than 2 Millions rows)

```
UPDATE first_table ft, second_table st SET ft.Dataset=3
WHERE st.Dataset =0
AND (ft.Dataset =1 || ft.Dataset=2)
AND (ft.ID IS NULL )
AND st.First_Name = ft.First_Name
AND st.Last_Name = ft.Last_Name
AND st.Zip = ft.Zip
```

OR

putting following into two different update query

```
(ft.Dataset =1 || ft.Dataset=2)
```

Comment: Actually that will depend more on your engine, index, table structure, datatype, etc...

Comment: yeah i have set indexes, table is in innodb

Comment: innodb should be run a little bit slower because it has to update index, if you separate the query in 2 I don't see how it will make a faster query, besides you are updating 2MM of rows

Comment: 2 million plus rows and you're joining the two tables on firstname, surname and zip - nice !!

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference, but you are better off testing it than simply guessing.

Logically it would be the same, but if it somehow will try to preload all the rows from both queries separately than it could be a lot slower (assuming you don't have the rows in memory).

Comment: yeah i was anticipating the same thing. Thanks.